# Combining conditions for CASE, mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to finish up a query to total different numbers for our people on the phones and I have the standard totals calculated fine, it seems, but I'm now trying to do this:

For every total column (total calls, total inbound, total outbound, total missed) I now need to have a new column partnered with it for known numbers in our database (so I'll have total calls known, total inbound known, etc.).

The way I'm doing this is by checking two fields in my `session` table: `callingpartyno` and `finallycalledpartyno`. So, for every call in `session` I need to check to see if the number in either of those fields are in my `knownNumbers` table in the `phone_number` field. If so, I need to count them for the known column.

About 8 lines down in my query below, I have my first instance of this which seems to be showing accurate numbers, but it's only incorporating `callingpartyno`. I first need to know how to combine conditions in this 'case when`to add`finallycalledpartyno` as well.

The other issue is that for inbound and outbound, I need to base the phone number field I'm using on the LEGTYPE field. So, for example, IF I'm calculating outbound calls to known numbers I need something like

```
sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AND finallycalledpartno = k.phone_number AS Total_Outbound_known.
```

I hope this makes sense, and it should be pretty straightforward for an advanced SQL programmer. I just can't seem to get the combination of conditions in a case when statement to work especially.

Query below:

```
SELECT u.firstn
      ,u.lastn
      ,c.extension
      ,SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
       SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound calls
       SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1))  AS Total_Calls
      ,sum(case when CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number  then 1 else 0 end ) AS total_known
      ,sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
      ,sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS Total_Recieved
      ,sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
      ,round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
      ,sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) / (SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
       SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound calls
       SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1)))  * 100 AS Percentage_Missed
FROM ambition.session a
INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b
ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
INNER join ambition.mxuser c
ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
INNER join jackson_id.users u
on c.extension = u.extension
left join ambition.knownnumbers k
on a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
WHERE b.ts between curdate() - interval 5 day and now()
AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
group by c.extension;
```

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: That's how I've been running my queries on this data for weeks and it works fine. When I remove it, it only gives me one row of data and one CSRs name, but it has all the cumulative totals for the CSRs. So instead of 15 rows with individual totals, I get one row with huge totals

Comment: to get help I suggest to post sample data and desired output

Comment: About the example you gave for Total_Outbound_known, I think you could use something like this:    `SUM (CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 AND finallycalledpartno = k.phone_number THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Outbound_known`

Comment: Yes, thank you @etsa I have been trying that convention and it seems to work for everything, I'm just still getting 0's for outbound known, but my other totals match up so it seems that the numbers may actually be accurate. I'm just testing to see if I need to add to my example here or not.

Comment: @TomN.   about Jarlh comment I think he didn't tell to remove group by but instead to add the other columns who are not in SUM in the group by clause.  In your case you should use `GROUP BY c.extension, u.firstn, u.lastn`

Comment: Oh I see, that makes more sense. I will make that change as well and check the data again

Comment: Moreover, I don't understain logic in your `SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
            SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound calls
            SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1))  AS Total_Calls`.  It seems to me the last condition is wrong and should be eliminated.

Comment: My logic is that it's summing outbound, inbound answered, and missed. Legtype = 1 is oubound, legtype = 2 is inbound and answered = 0 is missed. Would that not be correct

Comment: I see.  I think you can write it in this way too: `SUM (CASE WHEN LEGTYPE=1 OR LEGTYPE=2 AND ANSWERED=1 OR ANSWERED=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS TOTAL_CALLS`

Comment: Ah that's much more legible, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart what I wrote in above comments, I would rewrite your query like this (I think at least it should be easier to read it, avoiding to repeat some SUMs)

```
SELECT firstn
    , lastn
    , extension
    , Total_Outbound+Total_Missed+Total_Received AS Total_Calls
    , Total_Known
    , Total_Missed
    , Total_Received
    , Total_Outbound
    , Total_Talk_Time_minutes
    , Total_Missed  / (Total_Outbound+Total_Missed+Total_Received)  * 100 AS Percentage_Missed
FROM (
      SELECT u.firstn
    , u.lastn
    , c.extension       
    , sum(case when CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number  then 1 else 0 end ) AS Total_Known
    , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
    , sum(CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Received
    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
    , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
      FROM ambition.session a
      INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
      INNER join ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
      INNER join jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension
      LEFT JOIN ambition.knownnumbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
      WHERE b.ts between curdate() - interval 5 day and now()
      AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
      GROUP BY c.extension, u.firstn, u.lastn  
     ) X;
```